# Angular Language Service working in one project but not another

Tags: visual-studio-code, angular-language-service

I have two angular projects, open in separate VS Code instances.

- In one of the project, auto-completions and click-follows in templates works just fine.
- In the other, it does not work at all.

[image]

I can't for the love of god figure out what the difference between these projects is. tsconfig.json is exactly the same in both. One is angular 8.1 the other is 8.0 (the 8.0 is the working one).

Any ideas what is going on here, and in general, how to debug this kind issue in general, would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have de same problem and after check i see that:

https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/issues/343

the version of angular language service has a bug so, the solution at the moment is downgrade the @angular/language-service to version 8.0.3.

to do that execute: `npm i --save-dev @angular/language-service@8.0.3`